# como usar el login de laravel con otros campos?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

buenas, estoy usando larvel en mi sitio web, pues laravel hace la verificacion del login por mi, con los campos username y password pues yo quiero que no solo vea esos dos campos si no que tambien un capo de estdo

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varias opciones:

- Agregar la verificación de dicho campo en el middleware `Authenticate`, después de verificar correo y contraseña. Te doy una idea básica:

  ```
  if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->estado == 0) {
      // usuario no tiene el estado permitido para iniciar sesión
      Auth::logout();
  }
  ```
- Modificar un poco la forma como laravel verifica las credenciales al momento de iniciar sesión, tendrías que revisar y hacer las modificaciones en tu `LoginController`, como punto de partida revisa:

  - El método `credentials()` en Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php
  - El método `validateCredentials()` en Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php (asumiendo que usas Eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Para registrar añadir mas datos al auth que te genera laravel, lo haces en el archivo RegisterController que esta dentro de la carpeta App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

En ese archivo php encuentras el metodo create solo añades el campo 
**'estado' => $data['estado']** y para usar este campo: **Auth::user()->estado**